# Подскажите подробную инструкцию как перенести XML config (Spring и Spring Security,Web.xml)в Java Class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Подскажите подробную инструкцию как перенести XML config (Spring и Spring Security,Web.xml) в Java Class
или где взять подробный пример!)

Спасибо!!!

Прилагаю примеры кода( может кто то что то подскажет!)

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <display-name>Spring Security Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/appconfig-root.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

appconfig-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>

        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
                    username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"/>

        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl">
            <password-encoder ref="encoder"></password-encoder>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl"
                class="com.authorization.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl"></beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="encoder"
                class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11"/>
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

appconfig-root.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <import resource="appconfig-mvc.xml"/>

    <import resource="appconfig-data.xml"/>

    <import resource="appconfig-security.xml"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.authorization.*"/>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties"/>

</beans>
```

appconfig-mvc.xml

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:validation</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Откуда и куда перенести?

Comment: у меня написаны xml конфигурации и я хочу их перенести в Java классы

Comment: Что значить перенести в java классы? выполнить это всё программным образом или xml заменить аннотациями?

Comment: Да заменить Анотациями

Comment: Руководства по сервлетам и спрингу уже читали?

Comment: да читал не могу найти примеры которые можно было бы сопоставить

Comment: С web.xml скорей всего ничего не поделаешь. Ведь Вы используете уже готовые классы. Свои собственные фильтры, сервлеты, листенеры, действительно, можно объявить через аннотации, без xml.  Если только спринг не поможет. Но спрингом не владею.

Comment: Я видел что и web.xml полностью убирают. Хочу овладеть этим навыком.

Comment: Вы можете начать с этих руководств: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/guides/html5/helloworld-xml.html и http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/guides/html5/helloworld-javaconfig.html